# How to find the distribution of the weighted sum of independent Bernoulli random variables for positive non-integer weights

Tags: distributions, bernoulli-distribution

How do I find the distribution of the weighted sum of independent Bernoulli random variables if the weights are non-negative real numbers?

I have N number of independent  Bernoulli distributed random variables lets say $X_1, X_2, X_3...X_N$  and suppose I have a set of weights $W_1, W_2, W_3,...,W_N$ which are non-negative real numbers and the sum of all the weights is equal to $N$.

Then I need to find the distribution of the random variable $Z$ which is the weighted sum of the $N$ independent Bernoulli random variables
i.e,  $Z =\sum_i^N W_i*X_i$, where $i=1,2,\cdots,N$.

Comment: This is conditional on the $W$'s? Do the $X_i$ all share the same $p$?

Comment: No, all Xi have different probability P and I am assuming  the weight parameter W is constant for all Xi`s it doesn`t change. If Xi is highly probable then corresponding weight Wi will take large value between 0 and N. Thanks inadvance, Glen_b

Comment: Should answers be exact or approximate?

Comment: should be exact

Comment: Okay, but I don't think you'll much like the answer.

Comment: Will not give you exact answers, but might be very close: saddlepoint approximation. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/191781#191781  and search this site.

Comment: @Glen_b if they all shared the same $p$ and it didn't matter if it was approximate or exact would there be an answer? The weights in my situation may be dependent but the Bernoulli random variables are independent

Comment: When you say the weights are dependent, you're indicating that the *weights* are random variables rather than constants, unlike the situation here?