# How do I construct the likelihood function for a series of observed Bernoulli-distributed datapoints?

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, bernoulli-distribution

I have observed N (a_i, p_i) pairs each drawn from a different Bernoulli distribution. Here a_i are observed amplitudes and p_i are observed probabilities of success for the
i^{th} draw.

I would like to model the full likelihood distribution (and not just via the MLE) with a view to identifying which draws belong to the successful class (and hence the statistics of just these draws, especially any irregular uncertainty distributions etc.).

For example, I have

```py
a_i p_i p_true
10 0.2 0
100 0.9 1
11 0.1 0
99 0.93 1
12 0.25 0
```

I know the PDFs of the model and of the data (both are obviously Bernoulli distributions), but how do I combine them to obtain residuals that I can use to explore the joint distribution? What distribution does the joint distribution follow and how?

I have tried to unpack the cross-entropy and data and model but don't have a clear solution.

Is the continuous Bernoulli distribution a complete red herring?

Note that ordering doesn't matter in my example. Some other points in response to comments:

1. The p_i values come from an oracle - these represent the probabilities that the datapoints belong to a common class.
2. The amplitudes a_i are just weights for the corresponding Bernoulli distributions. The higher the amplitude, the higher the scaling of the Bernoulli distribution in its contribution to the overall process.

See also:

["Weighted" Poisson binomial distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277330/weighted-poisson-binomial-distribution)

[Weighted sum of Bernoulli distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569610/weighted-sum-of-bernoulli-distributions)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481907/sum-of-weighted-independent-bernoulli-rvs

[What is the CDF of the sum of weighted Bernoulli random variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270227/what-is-the-cdf-of-the-sum-of-weighted-bernoulli-random-variables)

Please let me know if you need any more information to assist in answering. Thanks as ever!

Comment: Is p_i directly observed or is it some modeled value based on a_i?

Comment: *"a_i are observed amplitudes"* amplitudes of what?

Comment: What is 'p_true' in your table? Is it the true value of p? How do you know it and why does it only have values 0 and 1?

Comment: p_i comes from an entirely separate model.

Comment: What model? Could you explain it.

Comment: *"Is the continuous Bernoulli distribution a complete red herring?"* This sentence is unclear. What is the 'continuous Bernoulli distribution' and how does it connect with the rest of the text?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Good point. I am getting at: Since I'd like to explore (sample from) the full likelihood, do I need to invoke a non-discrete version of the PDF?

Comment: *"weights for the corresponding Bernoulli distributions."* I don't have a clear idea what this means. Weights can occur in all sort of ways. The Bernoulli distribution has only a single parameter $p$, how you include the weight in your problem is unclear.

Comment: Each distribution is scaled in value by the weight (amplitude).

Comment: *"Each distribution is scaled in value"* What do you mean by scaling in value of distributions? I do not get this context.

Comment: Feel free to continue asking Qs - I will add clarification into the question as necessary

Comment: I believe that is is better to explain your concrete problem instead of using these abstract terms. None of my questions are really clarified.

Answer (score 0):

> I know the PDFs of the model and of the data (both are obviously Bernoulli distributions),

Bernoulli distributions are not characterized by a probability density function (PDF) and instead are characterized by a probability mass function (PMF).

> but how do I combine them to obtain residuals that I can use to
> explore the joint distribution?

In many problems the observations are assumed to be independent and are multiplied. For instance if you have two pmf's depending on some parameter $p$ like $$P(X_1=x_1;p) = f_1(x_1,p)$$ and $$P(X_2=x_2;p) = f_2(x_2,p)$$ then the pmf for the joint probability is $$P(X_1=x_1 \land X_2=x_2 ;p) = f_1(x_1,p)f_2(x_2,p)$$.

For Bernoulli distributions the observations $X_i$ are discrete, but the parameter $p$ is continuous. So if you use this to make a likelihood function, then you get a continuous function.